# Vulkan - Debugging A Camera Matrix Problem

Tags: c, matrix, 3d, vulkan

The problem I'm having is that I'm exporting a scene from Blender and my scene is rotated 90 about the Y axis. It's clearly a matrix issue and I'm having problems visualizing the solution. Blender is configured to export with 'up' = (0, 1, 0) and 'forward' = (0, 0, 1).

I'm using row major matrices as indicated by the following.

```
mat4x4 cons_mat4x4_perspective(float fovy, float aspect_ratio, float near, float far)
{
    mat4x4 result = cons_mat4x4_zero(); 
    float half_tan_fovy = tan(fovy / 2.0f); /* in radians */

    result.as_rows[0] = cons_vec4(1.0f / (aspect_ratio * half_tan_fovy), 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    result.as_rows[1] = cons_vec4(0.0f, 1.0f / half_tan_fovy, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    result.as_rows[2] = cons_vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, -(far + near) / (far - near), -1.0f);
    result.as_rows[3] = cons_vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, -(2.0f * far * near) / (far - near), 0.0f);
    
    return result;
}

// Vulkan clip matrix
clip = cons_mat4x4_floats(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                        0.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f,
                        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f);

mat4x4 cons_mat4x4_lookat(vec3 eye, vec3 center, vec3 up)
{
    mat4x4 result = cons_mat4x4_identity();

    vec3 f = normalize(vec3_sub(center, eye));
    vec3 s = normalize(cross(f, up));
    vec3 u = cross(s, f);

    result.as_rows[0] = cons_vec4(s.x, u.x, -f.x, 0.0f);
    result.as_rows[1] = cons_vec4(s.y, u.y, -f.y, 0.0f);
    result.as_rows[2] = cons_vec4(s.z, u.z, -f.z, 0.0f);
    result.as_rows[3] = cons_vec4(-vec3_dot(s, eye),
                              vec3_dot(u, eye),
                              vec3_dot(f, eye),
                              1.0f);
    return result;
}
```

My model matrix is the identity matrix and I'm creating a lookat matrix with the following parameters:

```
vec3 _camera = cons_vec3(0.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f);
vec3 _at = cons_vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

cons_mat4x4_lookat(_camera, _at, cons_vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
```

Comment: I'm just going by the last code block, but are you sure that block is correct? `center - eye` and `up` are contained in the same subspace, so the lookAt matrix won't even be a general linear transformation in this case.

Comment: Not at all. I can see the problem about it not being a linear xform.